NgxAnalyticsModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument
I have migrated my angular application from version 13 to version 17. When I am trying to do "ng serve" it is throwing below error.
NgxAnalyticsModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type.

I have followed the ngx-analytics documentation, by adding in app.module.ts as shown in below
app.module.ts
import { NgxAnalyticsModule } from 'ngx-analytics';
import { NgxAnalyticsPiwik } from 'ngx-analytics/piwik';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ...
  ],
  imports: [
     ...
     NgxAnalyticsModule.forRoot([NgxAnalyticsPiwik]),
     ...
  ],
  declarations: [
     ...
  ]
})

package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~17.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~17.3.4",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "ngx-analytics": "^4.6.3-patch1",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}

Any solution for the problem will be appreciated.

You are using a package that has last been updated 6 years ago, It's probably outdated and not compatible with newer version of Angular, I'd highly recommand to find and try another option.
